# Berryboot stuck on rainbow screen after update

Tags: raspbian, boot, update, berryboot

I have been using RetroPie and Raspbian with Berryboot for a month without any problems. While using Raspbian and ssh on Windows, I did `rpi-update` then rebooted but I now only see a rainbow screen. I am using the same power supply I have always used and tried adding `boot_delay=1` in the config but it is still not working.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You ran `rpi-update` which installs the latest development software which is untested and has a couple of known issues.

You should never do this unless you have some particular reason to run development.

On top of this Berryboot has its own loader which you have probably damaged.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when was upgrading kernel from 4.1.x to 4.4.x.

I resolved it by downloading kernel files directly from [repository](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware) and overwrite files in boot partition(Mounted in Windows).